# Prove that $F_{2n}(x)=0$ has exactly one root in the interval $x\in(0,1),$ and this root $\to 0$ when $n \to \infty.$

Tags: calculus, limits, roots, tetration, power-towers

Define $$f_1(x)=x\\f_2(x)=x^x\\\vdots\\f_{n+1}(x)=x^{f_n(x)}$$

Let $F_n(x)=f_n^{'}(x).$ Hence $$F_1(x)=1\\F_2(x)=x^x(1+\log(x))\\\vdots$$

> Prove that $F_{2n}(x)=0$ has exactly one root in the interval $x\in(0,1),$ and this root $\to 0$ when $n \to \infty.$

Here are the images of $f_{2n}(x)$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,10.$

[image]

Comment: @Jaycob Coleman How do you get this? I think $F_3(x)=0$ has no real roots.

Comment: @Hecke Do you have a source for this problem?

Comment: Since $f_n$ converges only for $x \in [e^{-e},e^{1/e}]$ I would expect that the root of $F_n$ tends to $e^{-e}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I checked this numerically, and it seems that the the roots do tend to $e^{-e}$, not $0$.